# Firefox read pdf via php only once

Tags: php, pdf, firefox, readfile, window.open

By clicking on a button, the PDF document is to be displayed in another fixed form. The php file looks like:

```
// filename is read_pdf.php

    $path = '../../pdfs';
    $code = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ac', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    if (isset($antcode) ) {

        $a = ... get the pdf-name from a mysql db as a function auf $code;

        $file = $path . '/' . $a;
    // Header content type 
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $a . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        @readfile($file);
    }
```

In jQuery, I start the filereading process:

```
var url ="php/read_pdf.php?ac=" + r.randid;
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

Everything's going well in Chrome. With Firefox it works fine with 'localhost'. But on the server Firefox manages to read the pdf once. With the next pdf nothing more is loaded. If I delete the cache, exactly one pdf can be loaded again. I have played with the 'Cache-Control', but nothing helps.

What may be the problem?

Comment: You should remove `header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');` because you do not handle the `Range` header from the request in your script. Also you should check that `r.randid` is really random for each "click" to bypass any cache problem.

Comment: I found the solution: Add:ob_clean();
    flush();

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that only Firefox need ob_clean and flush commands. Change the code to:

```
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');    
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
 ob_clean();
 flush();
 readfile($file);
```

now it works.

Comment: That means that you send invalid data to the client before you send the PDF. The right way would be to analyze what data you send to the client and fix this instead.